# TCP send semantics on linux

Tags: c, linux, tcp

My understanding about send() on linux is that if the sending process's data can be successfully copied into the kernel buffer, send() returns. The application is then free to move on.

1. If this is true, and say TCP is unable to deliver that packet, how does TCP report an error?
2. If error is received after multiple send()(Rwnd was large at beginning), how does application know, which particular send() failed or in other words, which message failed to reach?

Comment: What sort of "unable to deliver that packet"? Like, the packet is dropped, or the connection drops?

Comment: Say packet drop by intermediate router and tcp reached its max retries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If this is true, and say TCP is unable to deliver that packet, how does TCP report an error?

TCP will retry/resend silently until the connection ends or abends.

If you want to know whether it has been received, then you need the receiving application to send a confirmation (an application-level message).

---

**Edit:**

The TCP protocol receives an end-to-end ACK ... but that ACK is swallowed by the TCP stack: I don't think it's exposed to the application, via the normal 'sockets' API.

A packet sniffer hooks into the network/TCP stack at a level that enables it to see the ACK: see for example the answers to [How can I verify that a TCP packet has received an ACK in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1863101/49942) ... I don't know what the equivalent is for Linux, but there must be one.

Note [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1863141/49942) which warns that even if the message is received by the remote TCP stack, that doesn't guarantee that it has been processed (i.e. retrieved from the stack) by the receiving application.

Comment: Then i can simply use UDP and let application do all the error handling for a message which never received application ACK. From error reporting perspective, does TCP provide no help to sending application regarding which packet could not be delivered?

Comment: @Jimm TCP does a lot for you, which you'd have to implement yourself if you were using UDP: e.g. retries; congestion/flow control; reordering packets that arrive out-of-sequence.

Comment: @Jimm No, TCP does not provide you with any help in that regard. TCP just gives you a stream of bytes, not packets. Your own application packets needs to be handled at the application protocol layer, not the TCP transport layer. Implementing the features of TCP on top of UDP is very hard though, the benefits TCP give you with retransmission, reordering, congestion avoidance, flow control, connection handling, and so on are mostly invisible to you, but it will become highly visible once you implement(or ignore to implement them) yourself on top of UDP.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get an error *eventually* reported by another send or recv. *Eventually* - by default TCP can take a very long time to decide that there's a problem in the connection. You may get a whole selection of "successful" sends first, it depends on the error condition. You may only find out things have gone awry by send moaning that its buffer is full.

Comment: TCP maintains state about packets which have not been ack. When it finally decides it cannot deliver those packets, does it not provide any information to sending application?

Comment: That's a bit dependant on your platform and how you're looking for it. select or poll will offer an error condition, but you'll find out from send and recv too.