# How can you safely tell that a TCP/IP packet was received at the other end?

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient

In this project the protocol is to:

- Open Socket
- Send Data
- Wait for the acknowledgement message or timeout
- If ack arrives in the proper window all is well. close the socket
- If it times out, close the socket and start over up to N times.

I've noticed in the log that sometimes after the timeout we receive the ack anyway. Since the socket stays open for clean up and stragglers after the close I understand why.

But is there a better way to handle this?  I'd like to be sure the connection is really down before reporting something to a line operator.

The timeout right now is an arbitrary value (2.5 seconds) tied to an external timer. It is not in the .Net TCP stack.

Comment: Maybe something useful here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863101/how-can-i-verify-that-a-tcp-packet-has-received-an-ack-in-c

Comment: When you talk about receiving "ack", are you talking about the basic TCP/IP ACK, or a home-made acknowledge message?

Comment: For what it's worth, I've made some TCP/IP routines on top of .Net's Socket class, as a home-made alternative to WCF. To ensure the connection is still alive I send a ping message every 30 seconds, and check that I've received a ping within the last 90 seconds, if not I assume the connection is lost.

Comment: @RenniePet The ACK I'm watching is from application. So far in the initial live tests I'm seeing that most of the time it happens on the first try, but sometimes it does take another attempt. In those times I sometimes receive a late acknowledgement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TCP connection isn't really down unless the socket closes on your side. It takes minutes for TCP to decide the connection is down and close the socket if it doesn't receive any response from the network after sending data.

Comment: I'm no expert, but in my experience Windows NEVER closes the socket due to there not being any traffic on the connection. Or maybe that's because I set ReceiveTimeout to zero? (Of course, this isn't what the OP is asking about ...) Anyway, my suggestion to the OP is that he implement some kind of pinging, and make his own decision about whether the connection is usable or not. Don't count on Windows or .Net to make that decision.

Comment: A TCP connection will stay connected for years even if no data is transferred. The connection times out only if it tries to send data and cannot get an ACK back.

Comment: @Fred The customer's system requests a new connection for every transaction. It simplifies their parsing of the data. My concern is how to know when to throw in the towel and decide the host isn't reliable.

Comment: You could run some heatbeat app in parallel on the same machines if you have a hard requirement for responsiveness.

Comment: @Fred Possibly but the connection is only alive for the duration of one transaction. The next transaction has its own connection.

Comment: Right, but you were concerned about the state of the network. Heartbeat monitoring tells you if the network/remote-side is up, so you can distinguish that from your application crashing.

Comment: @Fred No my goal is not to check the state of the network, it is to know that a packet is received.

Answer (score 0):

The sockets abstraction layers a bidirectional stream over the TCP channel. The user only sees that the stack has accepted the fragment when Write() (or equivalent) returns successfully, and when Read() returns a non-zero number of characters. The lower levels are opaque. For you to be certain that the server has received and acknowledged your data, you need confirm that the Read() returns the expected amount of data within your allowed time period.

As you have to connect a new session for each request, you have little choice but to tear down the session to make way for the next one. In particular, you can't leave a session around as the server may not allow multiple concurrent connections.

You state that the timeout is 2.5 seconds. If this is much smaller than the message interval, is there a problem if the timeout is extended to something close to the interval. This would appear to be more reliable that hammering away with multiple rapid requests of the same data.